# How can I make this function recursive/run until the requirements are not met?

Tags: javascript, recursion

As of now, I can only hardcode the same snippet after every if statement, which only needs to have the argument that getAdjacentCells(id) takes changed. I haven't been able to find a way to repeat this part. I think this can be done recursively, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit: I initially typed that isCellEmpty got an array of objects: [{topLeft: null}, {topCenter: "cell-1-2"}, {topRight: "cell-1-3"}, {middleLeft: null}, {middleRight: "cell-2-3"}], when in reality it is a single object: {topLeft: null, topCenter: "cell-1-2", topRight: "cell-1-3", middleLeft: null, middleRight: "cell-2-3"}

```
// Gets an object that looks like this: {topLeft: null, topCenter: "cell-1-2", topRight: "cell-1-3", middleLeft: null, middleRight: "cell-2-3"}
function isCellEmpty(adjacentCells) {
  Object.values(adjacentCells).forEach(id => {
    // Checks that the ids in stored in the object values do not equal null
    if (id !== null) {
      board[getBoardPosition(id)].opened = true;
      // getAdjacentCells() will return either an array of objects similar to the one the function takes as an argument or an integer
      // if getAdjacentCells(id) returns a number, add a div to the HTML element with that id
      if (typeof (getAdjacentCells(id)) === "number") {
        // Removes all other divs, this prevents repetition
        $("#" + id).empty();
        // Appends an empty div
        $("#" + id).append("<div></div>");
      // HERE'S WHERE IT STARTS: If getAdjacentCells(id) returns an object, do the same as above with every id in it
      } else if (typeof (getAdjacentCells(id)) === "object") {
        Object.values(getAdjacentCells(id)).forEach(id2 => {
          if (id2 !== null) {
            board[getBoardPosition(id2)].opened = true;
            if (typeof (getAdjacentCells(id2)) === "number") {
              $("#" + id2).empty();
              $("#" + id2).append("<div></div>");
            // HERE IT REPEATS: 
            } else if (typeof (getAdjacentCells(id2)) === "object") {
              ... 
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The name of the function seems to suggest it should return a boolean, but you don't really return anything? Is that intentional?

Comment: No, the only thing it does is set the "opened" key of the id in the board as true, add a div and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the recursive call with the value you get from `getAdjacentCells`. Make sure however to call `getAdjacentCells` only once for the same `id`. Now it is quite inefficient as you repeat the same call.

See also some other suggestions in the code.

```
function isCellEmpty(adjacentCells) {
    // I would move this check here, although not necessary if you prefer it in the loop.
    if (typeof adjacentCells === "number") {
        $("#" + id).empty().append("<div>"); // You can chain jQuery...
        return;
    } 
    for (let id of adjacentCells) { // Just use a for..of loop
        if (id === null) continue; // keep IF-ELSE nesting flat.
        let cell = board[getBoardPosition(id)];
        if (cell.opened) continue; // Add this to avoid circling around
        cell.opened = true;
        isCellEmpty(getAdjacentCells(id)); // recursive call
    }
}
```

#### Object.values

You write in the comments of your code that:

> getAdjacentCells() will return either an array of objects similar to the one the function takes as an argument or an integer

However, your comments below this answer seem to suggest that this is not (always) the case. It maybe a plain object which would explain why you used `Object.values` to iterate it. If this is the case I would urge to change `getAdjacentCells` so that it really does return an array. Or if that is not possible then use `Object.values` like you already did:

```
function isCellEmpty(adjacentCells) {
    // I would move this check here, although not necessary if you prefer it in the loop.
    if (typeof adjacentCells === "number") {
        $("#" + id).empty().append("<div>"); // You can chain jQuery...
        return;
    } 
    for (let id of Object.values(adjacentCells)) { // Just use a for..of loop
        if (id === null) continue; // keep IF-ELSE nesting flat.
        let cell = board[getBoardPosition(id)];
        if (cell.opened) continue; // Add this to avoid circling around
        cell.opened = true;
        isCellEmpty(getAdjacentCells(id)); // recursive call
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get "adjacentCells is not iterable" when I try it.

Comment: But you wrote in your code comments that getAdjacentCells returns an array or integer. So is it something else?

Comment: To avoid these kinds of issues it would be helpful to provide code that can be run, so including the defintion of that function.

Comment: See addition to my answer, with explanation of why this happens.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. I actually made a mistake when typing out the code, I thought that the "object" data type that getAdjacentCells() returned was an array of objects of single keys, when in reality it was a single object with several keys. Still, you guessed right, and using Object.values solved the problem. Thanks again, your answer besides correct is also very readable, I didn't know how to use recursion as I had never done it before but I think I understand it better now.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion should work just fine here: at its most basic you'd call your own method with `id2`. However, assuming `getAdjacentCells` may return cells that you've already visited, you'll end up recursing infinitely unless you're able to track which IDs you've already visited, and pass that in.

```
function setCellState(id, visited) {
  if(id === null) {
    return;
  }
  if(visited === undefined) {
    visited = new Set();
  }
  if(visited.has(id)) {
    return;
  }
  visited.add(id);

  board[getBoardPosition(id)].opened = true;

  // getAdjacentCells() will return either an array of objects similar to the one the function takes as an argument or an integer
  let adjacentCells = getAdjacentCells(id);
  // if getAdjacentCells(id) returns a number, add a div to the HTML element with that id
  if (typeof (adjacentCells) === "number") {
        // Removes all other divs, this prevents repetition
        $("#" + id).empty()
          // Appends an empty div
          .append("<div></div>");
  } else if (typeof (adjacentCells) === "object") {
    Object.values(adjacentCells).forEach(id2 => setCellState(id2, visited));
  }
```

I took the liberty of changing the method name to be more representative of what the method actually does. I also changed it to start with a single cell's ID, since that simplifies the recursion and that allows the comment around the behavior of `getAdjacentCells` to provide better context.

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I try it I get a syntax error both on my editor (VSCode) and the console. It's this part which causes it: else if (typeof (adjacentCells)) === "object")

Comment: I just had too many closing parentheses there. Change it to `else if (typeof (adjacentCells) === "object")`.